# Get php variable string from Database

Tags: php, database, variables, eval

I try to do the following:

I have a script that uses diffrent codes to retrieve from a xml file. I try to store those in the database.

An example is:

```
str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace,preg_replace('!\s+!', '-', $permanameproduct))
```

When I retrieve this frome the database I get this it as a string, but i would like it to return the value from expression.

Is there a way I can do this in PHP, I was trying to use eval() but i could not get it working so far.

Thanks :)

Comment: You need to show some code where you tried `eval` then. Just saying you tried it is not enough

Comment: I just tried is like this: $name = eval($name.";");

Comment: You need a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code. That's not enough.